# getting data from external webservice

Tags: magento2, php, web-services

I tried to get data from outside webservice.
I got API url like `http://wsq.check.com:50001/Services/appsspg.asmx/GetActionLog`and the data for the function is `$data = array("parameter1" => "1");`. So, how could i get the data from that external webservice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access external webservice, you can use `Zend HTTP Client` class, using the below code:

```
protected $_httpClientFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
) {
    $this->_httpClientFactory   = $httpClientFactory;
}

/**
 * Function to create CURL Request to External Server
 */
public function connect()
{
        $data['parameter1'] = 1;

        $client = $this->_httpClientFactory->create();
        $client->setUri($url);
        $client->getUri()->setPort($port);
        $client->setConfig(['timeout' => 300]);
        $client->setHeaders(['Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json']);
        $client->setMethod(\Zend_Http_Client::POST);
        $client->setRawData(json_encode($data));

        try {
            $responseBody = $client->request()->getBody();

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($responseBody);
            die;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so, where did i place the url http://wsq.check.com:50001/Services/appsspg.asmx/GetActionLog ?

Comment: ah sry, i dont see the $url part. But where could i find the port?

Comment: In your case port is `50001`

Comment: should the url be "http://wsq.check.com:50001/Services/appsspg.asmx?wsdl" or "http://wsq.check.com:50001/Services/appsspg.asmx/GetActionLog" ?

Comment: it should be `GetActionLog` url.